# Vendoring package which resides in another project's vendor folder

Tags: go, govendor, vendoring

I'm writing a library package which depends on certain imports but I'm not sure how to handle it correctly.

Let me start with the directory structure:

```
go/src/github.com/
├── developer A/
│   ├── project 1
│   └── project 2
│   
└── developer B/
    └── project 3
        └── vendor
            └── project 4
```

Project 1 is a library. It is used in project 2 and gets pulled into 2s vendor folder. Therefore, project 1 should contain all its dependencies such that clients (e.g. project 2) don't need to pull them as well. However, one dependency of project 1 is project 4 which is contained in project 3s vendor folder. It is essential that this dependency is always exactly the version vendored by project 3. Go doesn't allow imports to point to packages inside vendor folders, so I can't import it directly from there. How do I solve this with govendor?

Comment: Do you control project 3?  As a rule, libraries should not vendor their dependencies--only end-products should. Libraries should instead declare their dependencies using `dep` or a similar tool.

Comment: No, I don't control project 3. I control projects 1 and 2. I tried to pull the same version of project 4 into project 2s vendor folder but this doesn't work as Go thinks these are different types because they are in different repositories.

Answer (score 2):

Go won't let you reach into another project's vendor directory. It sounds like your intention is to ensure versions. This is what `go modules` are tasked to do. Take a look at the [wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) for more information.

Comment: This looks good. However, I'm stuck with Go 1.9.4 for now and can't use modules.

Comment: What about using `glide` or `godep`?

Comment: Those would also work, however I must advise that you consider upgrading as go1.9 stopped being supported when go1.11 was released. I also tend to throw caution at teams picking up non `go mod` as that is likely to be the winner in this domain.